# what is the right expression to remove part of a string starts with EN/ in a string?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to delete lang-code(**EN/DE/FR/IT/JA/ES**) out of a string but i dont know the right expression can someone help me ?
the Lang-code string always starts with EN/ and the end is variable
i know i can delete this with preg_match but i diddnt understand the regex expressions...
my code so far:

```
$string = 'some string EN/DE/FR/IT/JA/ES some string' 
$new_string = preg_match('/ - (.*?)/', $string, $match);
$final_string = str_replace ($match[1], '', $new_string);
```

$final_string should return 'some string some string' does someone know the right expression for preg_match and can help me to understand regex a little more?

Comment: I suggest you to follow some tutorials about RegExes, Stackoverflow isn't a substitute to a learning platform. Giving you the correct pattern keys in hand won't help you neither, because you'll be stuck when you'll have to maintain it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Thank you @cid https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/14619937 - helped me alot